# Car stats for NFS: Hot Pursuit?

Tags: xbox-360, need-for-speed-hot-pursuit-2010

Does anyone know where I can find a list of all the cars and their stats (both racers and police cruisers)? I'm mainly interested in seeing the stats that are presented when you select the cars in the time before a race, but if the list includes overall health/offensive strength that would be awesome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The link [here](http://hotpursuit.needforspeed.com/game-info/cars) shows a lot of information about each car (more information once the car name is clicked on).

-Hope this helps!